# Spring MVC - permission for user and non-registered guest.. how?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm creating an Online Shopping System (very basic web app) and now I wondering... I want in order to couple things on my home page won't be visible for guest, but will be visible for logged in user (for example "cart" option on JSP page will be only visible for users) Do I have to create two JSP files for them and probably different controllers? for example JSP home page for users and JSP home page for guests?

Comment: You don't have to create 2 jsp files, unless the layouts for registered users would differ greatly from that of guests. Just use some flow control like if(reg_user) showUserGui()

Comment: use Spring Security library to control the access of your html page content/element. http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/18/spring-security-at-view-layer-using-jsp-taglibs/

Comment: thank you guys, I'll try with Spring Security :)